# Node.js --harmony : what alternative for callee/caller at strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

how I could get name of function that call my function?

previously I use callee/caller, but currently application use strict mode

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? How does having a reference to a calling function help with the solution?

Comment: I wrap few classes (all methods of classes) for logging. And when I wrap class and set it to another class method - can't detect name of wrapped method

Comment: Please provide example code so it's easier to follow what issue you are having.