# How to get caller function within a class?

Tags: javascript

```
class main {
  constructor(){}
  action(){
    Hello();
  }
}

function Hello() {
  console.log(Hello.caller);
  console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
}

(new main()).action();
```

Neither `Function.caller` nor `arguments.callee.caller` work if the caller function is within a class.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The problem is only indirectly related to classes, the actual  reason is that classes are always in strict mode and both `caller` and `callee` are not available in strict mode. Previous question, no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30080305/218196 . I can only repeat the comment here: Which problem are trying to solve by accessing `caller`?

Comment: The requirement is log caller function if there is a runtime error and report it back to the logger.

Comment: In this scenario why would a stack trace not suffice?

Comment: Yeah the current version just upload a stack trace. But I guess it could be useful in other scenarios too if I can find out how to accomplish this.